# Is Lambda required for Alexa App development?

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

Is Amazon Lambda required to make a fully functional Alexa voice application? If so, what can and cannot be done if Lambda is not desired?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can create your own secure endpoint and configure that to your Alexa skill. You will be able to accomplish pretty much everything lambda can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have lambda or any hosted endpoint as your Alexa backend.

However, having lambda will help you easy integration with services within AWS like using dynamodb/redshift/s3 etc...

And moreover, the price of keeping your backend running in lambda is very much less/negligible as you can have tons of requests served in less than few dollars.

Comment: You won't need one as long as your alexa skill is going to respond only static answers/responses. For dynamic response, you would need a backend